# How to read json string files in dataframe with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have some sample file which has json string in file how to process this type of file in spark.

Sample file

```
{"Id":"240","Page":"dashboard","test":"working"}
{"Amt": "0.0","deliveryfee": "Free","ProductList": "{{ProductId=1,Price=200,Quantity=1},{ProductId=2,Price=600,Quantity=1}}","sample": "data"}
```

Reading of file as json

```
val data = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json("/data/test/test.json")

df.printSchema
root
 |-- Amt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ProductList: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deliveryfee: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sample: string (nullable = true)
```

printSchema is showing **ProductList** as String but it is not.

Comment: Well it kinda is a String

Comment: @Pedro yeah i am getting data like this. so how to covert it to proper json format and save it back in hdfs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
{
"Amt": "0.0",
"deliveryfee": "Free",
"ProductList": [{
    "ProductId": 1,
    "Price": 200,
    "Quantity": 1
}, {
    "ProductId": 2,
    "Price": 600,
    "Quantity": 1
}],
"sample": "data"
```

}
Edited: The point is that the way your JSON in that field is a String, you need to change your JSON, or work with that field as a String

Comment: this is not even a valid JSON

Comment: yeah i know it's not valid json but i need to process the file in spark.

Comment: so is there any way to process this string file and save as valid string.

Comment: you can try to map that string with regex and transform it into, per example the Json I said